# how to retrieve table from database using AngularJS in Java

Tags: java, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

how to retrieve table from database using AngularJS in Java. Please provide one example.

```
try{  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:name of server:3306/DNName","Username","Password");  

            Statement stmt=(Statement) con.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rs=(ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery("select * from Tablename");  

            while(rs.next())  
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  
            con.close();  

            }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Not Connected --"+e);
                }  

            }
```

Comment: how you can use angularJS code in Java program ??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fetch data from database with the help of angularJS.

In your case you should fetch data from database with java and return that table data in JSON format to the client. Now you can use angularJS to render this data.

Answer (score 0):

Directly you can not get the data using Angular JS . follow some steps

- get you data from database using java code .
- o/p database code convert into JSON format .
- pass your JSON Url inside Angular JS function .

Thanks .

Comment: can you provide any simple example for same. actually i am new to AngularJS.

Comment: can you tell me what o/p you are getting from Database

Comment: Below is the sample data format which i have retrieved from database.

1 Apple Fruit
2 Tomato Fruit
3 Tea  Snacks

Answer (score 0):

So your JSON Will be like as 
`[{"1": "Apple Fruit "},{"2": "Tomato Fruit"},{"3": "Tea Snacks"}]`

- So this JSON URL you can call on angular JS function